# FCM push notification working in Foreground and Background but not working when app is closed

Tags: android, ios

I have implemented Firebase but unfortunately notifications are only working when app is in Foreground or Background but unable to receive any notification when app is closed. I tried surfing online but couldn't get any results. 
Is there any way to keep app alive in background even after closing it?
If yes i think this will help to receive notifications. Any helpful suggestions are entertained. Thanks

Comment: Show the codes how you had implemented.

Answer (score 0):

One thing i do is that i don't rely on the notification response, I rather pass the data object and make a custom notification myself.

Here is the code that might help you as we can access the data object even when app is open as well as closed:

```
Map<String, String> dataMap = remoteMessage.getData();
String notif = dataMap.get("title");
```

Then i use this function to make a notification

```
 private void notificationManager(Context context, String message) {

    try {
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Log.v("message", "," + message);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class);


        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name));
        builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message));
        builder.setContentText(message);
        builder.setTicker(message);
        builder.setLights(Color.GREEN, 500, 500);
        builder.setWhen(when);
        builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        builder.setContentIntent(intent);


        Notification notification = builder.build();
        notification.ledARGB = 0xFFff0000;
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
        notification.ledOnMS = 100;
        notification.ledOffMS = 100;
        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");
        wl.acquire(15000);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

FCM has two messaging services

1. **Display messaging**
2. **Data messaging**

Probably you are using display messaging. You should use data messaging instead of display messaging. Display messaging won't work when app is closed.